# For every continuous, real valued function: does $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R} \implies x_n \to x$ in $M$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I saw this problem while studying for my course in *Metric Spaces* and decided to take a crack at it:

> Suppose that we are given a point $x$ and a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in a metric space $M$, and let $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ for every **continuous**, real valued function $f$ on $M$. Does it follow that $x_n \to x$ in $M$?

Note that I used the conclusions from the following problem (that I solved previously): if $d$ is a metric on $M$, show that $|d(x,z) - d(y,z)| \leq d(x,y)$ and conclude that the function $f(x) = d(x,z)$ is continuous on $M$ for any fixed $z \in M$.

Here is my work:

---

We know that the function $f(x) = d(x,z)$ is continuous for any fixed $z \in M$. Therefore, fix $x \in M$ and let $\{x_n\} \subset M$. So, if $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (equipped with the standard metric), then $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$. However, from knowing that $f(x_n) = d(x_n,x)$ since $x$ is fixed, $|f(x_n) - f(x)| \leq d(x_n,x)$. So $|f(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ whenever $d(x_n,x) < \epsilon$ such that $n \geq N$. So $x_n \to n$ in $M$.

Is this correct? I feel like I have all the concepts and definitions where they need to be, however I still have my doubts. Any criticism is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite see how you conclude that $x_n \to x$ from your penultimate sentence. However, if you just use the function $f(y) = d(y,x)$ and plug in $y = x_n$, then you arrive at the conclusion directly because $f(x) = 0$.

EDIT: Now I see what you are doing. You should replace $|f(x_n)-f(x)| < d(x_n,x)$ by $|f(x_n)-f(x)| = d(x_n,x)$ and then your proof is fine.

Comment: One question: why does $f(x) = 0$ ?

Comment: Well, $d(x,x) = 0$ by definition of the metric.

Comment: Of course, and that makes total sense now that you could just plug $y = x_n$ and arrive at the conclusion directly. Thank you for your feedback, Klaus!